# How to reduce VOC of solar panels to match the MPPT of inverter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, inverter, high-voltage, mppt

I will have an off grid solar panel system to run my deep well 5,5 Hp water pump. I already got 24 of 250Wp 36,3 Voc panels and 3 phase Delta VFD C2000 inverter/driver. for this system I need to wire all the panels in serial to get 540-800 Voc for pump driver. This part is ok.

I want to use another 5KVA inverter with some batteries to run devices (Tv, Fridge, ...) in a small village house and 1-2 Hp small 230v motors for spraying (only during the day). I already have 24 panels for waterpump and I want to use those panels when I don't need water. However inverter can take up to 90 Voc 50 amps to charge 48V batteries. I can use some relays and make few parallel panel until 50 amp, but this system might be risky in the case of a relay fault.

If it is possible I want to reduce high Voc to match 90 Vmax 50 amps inverter input for solar panels.
Efficiency of dc to dc conversion is not and issue since I will have plenty of panels waiting all day for nothing.

Can you please give me and idea how can I do this with low budget?

Comment: Can you add a diagram of what you're proposing? Following the words is rather difficult. Using relays to reconfigure the panels makes sense, but I don't understand what "relay fault" you're worried about.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, it seems that connecting a DPDT relay to each pair of panels would achieve what you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi9lDe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Activate relays as needed to power the LV inverter. If a relay should drop out for some reason, there's no danger of exceeding the input voltage rating of the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

We all have temptation of taking MAX from MPPT controllers but should realise that for longevity of system we should never go to maximum limits of VOC or amperage.
Best is to invest little more on MPPT and get best from panels.